# SQLite can´t put data in database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I´m having given Error in my Android App concerning SQLlight and don´t know what to do about it. Im pretty new to coding and didn´t find something helpful. So Here´s the logcat error:

> 2020-03-21 19:35:09.157 12866-12866/com.lsh.homeauto E/SQLiteLog: (1)
>   near "Adress": syntax error 2020-03-21 19:35:09.159
>   12866-12866/com.lsh.homeauto E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Device
>   Adress=jsjsjs Device Name=ehdhds
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Adress": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   LED_Status(Device Adress,Device Name) VALUES (?,?)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:33)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1597)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1468)
>           at com.lsh.homeauto.DatabaseHelper.insertData1(DatabaseHelper.java:73)
>           at com.lsh.homeauto.ui.list_of_devices.list_of_devicesFragment$2.onClick(list_of_devicesFragment.java:63)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
>           at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

My code corresponding with the error is:

Databasehelper:

```
  public boolean insertData1(String Adress,String DeviceName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, Adress);
    contentValues.putNull(COL_2);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,DeviceName);
    contentValues.putNull(COL_4);
    contentValues.putNull(COL_5);
    long result = db.insert(Table_Name,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

}

And the Code from the fragment:

```
public  void AddData() {
    button_add_device.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData1(editText_device_id.getText().toString(),
                            editText_device_name.getText().toString());
                    if(isInserted == true)
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

The only clues I have about the origin of the error are the given Error and that it always jumps to the "Data not inserted" toast.

I hope you can help me,
Cheers!

Comment: "SQLiteException: near "Adress": syntax error"

Comment: If the columns of your table have names: `Device Adress` and `Device Name` change them to `[Device Adress]` and `[Device Name]` because spaces are not allowed. You may have to uninstall the app and rerun.

Comment: Can you please post your table structure? I want to see the column names and the types. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick replies!

My table structur would be:

 public static final String DATABASE_NAME="HomeAuto.db";
    
public static final String Table_Name="LED_Status";
    
public static final String COL_1="Device Address";

    public static final String COL_2="Groups";

    public static final String COL_3="Device Name";


    public static final String COL_4="Device on/off";

    public static final String COL_5="Colorcode";

And changing the collum names didn´t help ^^

Comment: If you enclosed **all** the names in square brackets now uninstall the app from the device and rerun. If the problem persists then try a clean device. Your problem is **the names of the columns**.

Comment: I´ve done that and even created a new virtual device and still get the same error...

I think the problem liese withinth the "while compiling: INSERT INTO LED_Status(Device Adress,Device Name) VALUES (?,?) at" questionarks and something doesn´t convert quiet right...

Comment: Did you see the error log: `...near "Adress"...`? Your code has: `String COL_1="Device Address"` so the name of the column should have 2 `d`s but the actual name has only 1 `d`. Fix the column names.

Comment: But that´s just a variable name, isn´t it? Not to say I didn´t try that, but I didnot find a combination that worked :/

Comment: No it is not the variable's name. Your insert statement is interpreted to: `INSERT INTO LED_Status(Device Adress,Device Name) VALUES (?,?)`. Read the error log carefully.